# Radio button error for name attribute in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I upgraded to React 16 and I am getting this error which I guess might be related to this upgrade.

I have a few radio buttons like below:

```
<input type="radio" name="booking-option" value={id}/>
```

and I am getting this error:

```
ReactDOMInput: Mixing React and non-React radio inputs with the same `name` is not supported.
```

I need to group the radio buttons using name property. Do you know how can I get this fixed?

more core requested:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import BookingOption from './BookingOption';
    const BookingSliderItem = ({title, options}) => {

        return (
            <div className="booking-departures__slider-item">
                <h3>{title}</h3>
                {
                    options.map((option) => <BookingOption key={option.id} {...option}/>)
                }
            </div>
        );

    };

    export default BookingSliderItem;
```

and

```
import React from 'react';
import {RadioButtonGroup} from '../../forms';

const BookingOption = ({ name, description, image, singleSharePrice, twinSharePrice, id }) => {
    const style = {
        backgroundImage: `url(${image})`
    };
    return (
        <div className="booking-option">
            <h4>{name}</h4>
            <div>{description}</div>
            <div style={style}/>
            <div>
                <span>${singleSharePrice.amount}/pp</span>
                <span>Single Share</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>${twinSharePrice.amount}/pp</span>
                <span>Twin Share</span>
            </div>
            <input type="radio" name="booking-option" value={id}/>
        </div>
    );
};

export default BookingOption;
```

Comment: you may want to push a more complete code. just to make sure you are not "mixing react and non-react radio inputs"

Comment: Do you have a radio button in vanilla HTML, or created outside of react with javascript/jquery, that has that name?

Comment: I added more code - radio buttons are in react component. So no j query... Having said that I am using jquery for Slick carousel....

Comment: You just gave me the hint @AndyRay. I removed the initialising slick carousel and I am not getting error anymore...

Comment: If you need both elements, you could always change the "name" for the react elements, and map it somewhere else. in general with React development, we expect all or most of the page HTML to be rendered by React. Looks like you hit an edge case where some things are outside react.

Comment: "If you need both elements, you could always change the "name" for the react elements, and map it somewhere else" this is cool any code example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React does not allow you to use `name` attribute in input tag anymore. To make a distinct selection, you use attribute `checked = {true}` and toggle the selection with `onChange` method. I can show you an example how to radio button it without using `name`

```
this.state = {
  selected_id: "a"
};

changeID(new_id){
  this.setState({ selected_id: new_id });
}
```

And your radio input will look like

```
<input type="radio" value={id} checked={this.state.selected_id === "a"} onChange={()=>this.changeID(id)}/>A
<input type="radio" value={id} checked={this.state.selected_id === "b"} onChange={()=>this.changeID(id)}/>B
```